# After encoding the variable which contains amount , it converts the variable type to string

Tags: php

I want to convert variable to float type,but when i encode it to json format it is converted to string format.
This is the way I am coverting it,
$amt =0.1;
$amt = number_format($amt,7);
Now, variable value is like :  0.1000000
And **after json encoding it is converted to string type like : {"amount":"0.1000000"}
But want it as : {"amount":0.1000000}**

Please help , how to maintain the float type even if it is json encoded

Comment: `number_format` is the thing that is producing a string. Why do you need your float to be `0.1000000`?! That's exactly the same value as `0.1`.

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate of what I think you're *actually* asking for. Note that there's no way to have a float with trailing zeros, because it makes no sense. If you really need that, you'll have to write your own JSON serialiser.

Comment: every time the amount will not be 0.1 it may be 1, 2 or 0.03893875748, etc. So here I want it to limit upto 7 decimals and use the float type as it is in json format , but it turns to string format when encoded

Answer (score 0):

```
 $amt = 0.1; 
 $amt = number_format($amt,7);
 echo gettype($amt);

//string

echo 0.1000000;
//0.1;
```

> you can use parseFloat or similar function when will get that json

Comment: I don't see how your code has any relation to the question. `gettype()`? see deceze comment under OP post

Comment: gettype show for you that number_format returns a string type data!!!